# Sort a list by a to-report procedure

Tags: simulation, netlogo

So I'm trying to sort a list by its value when computed with a reporter procedure I created. Here is the code:

```
globals [ goal Smin Smax distWeight colorWeight ]
turtles-own [ S Ac ]

to setup
  ca
  set Smin 2
  set Smax 6
  set distWeight 2
  set colorWeight 3

  ask n-of n patches [
    sprout 1 [ 
      set color one-of [ red blue ] 
      set heading one-of [ 90 270 ]
      set S []
      ]

  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [

    foreach sort other turtles [
      ask ? [
        if Smin < Sim myself ? [
          if Sim myself ? < Smax [
            set S lput ? S
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]

    ;how do I do this? this does not work
    set Ac max-one-of S [Sim myself ?]

  ]
  tick
end

to-report Sim [Ame Ao]
  report (Sfcolor Ame Ao * colorWeight) + (Sfdistance Ame Ao * distWeight)
end

to-report Sfcolor [Ame Ao]
  ifelse [color] of Ame = [color] of Ao 
  [ report 1 ]
  [ report 0 ]
end

to-report Sfdistance [Ame Ao]
  report 1 / euclidean-distance [xcor] of Ame [ycor] of Ame [xcor] of Ao [ycor] of Ao 
end

to-report euclidean-distance [x y x1 y1]
  report sqrt ((x1 - x) ^ 2  + (y1 - y) ^ 2)
end

to-report Gain [ SimVal ]
  report ( Smax - Smin ) / Smax - SimVal
end
```

Now I want a variable named `Ac` to contain the turtle that is an element of S that has the highest value of Sim. I'm trying to do this by

```
set Ac max-one-of S [Sim myself ?]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Gannicus, I think you'll get help more quickly if (a) you explain in what sense it doesn't work, and (b) you take out everything out of the code that doesn't matter to the problem, and create a "minimum working example" that illustrates the problem.  You may figure out the answer on your own when you do that, but if not it will be easier for people to help.  Most people don't want to read through a lot of code that's not really relevant to the problem that another programmer is experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you said exactly why it didn't work.

But for starters, that statement is outside of the foreach loop, so ? won't mean anything.